# Eagle: the holes don't come with the component

Tags: eaglecad

Well, I am completely baffled! I created some components with holes, and when I move the component while laying out the board, the holes do not move with the component. Rather the holes just stay outside the board, in the parts default position. Please see the image below [image]

I moved the chip, and the holes (14 little white circles in the bottom right) did not come along for the ride. How can I make them move with the component?

Comment: Post the design. Someone who uses Eagle (I don't) might be able to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: The holes should be part of the pads defined in the package in the library.  You shouldn't add deliberate holes separately, neither in the package and especially not manually in the board.

Comment: @Olin The holes are part of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away after restarting eagle. Must have been a bug.

Comment: What version of Eagle are you using?  The brand-new, potentially buggy 6.0 or the tried-and-tested 5.X series?

Comment: It might just have been a display artefact. Did you try refreshing the display?

Comment: I am using 6.0. Yes, I tried refreshing the display.